# wp custom login page - redirect not working

Tags: wordpress

Hoping someone can help me out with this, I've been looking around for a few days to no avail. I've set up a custom login page for a website's users, but can't seem to redirect to the home page instead of the admin page when a user logs in.

Here's my function:

```
<?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { // Display WordPress login form:
    $args = array(
        'redirect' => home_url(), 
        'form_id' => 'loginform-custom',
        'label_username' => __( 'what is your name?' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'what is your password?' ),
        'label_remember' => __(''),
        'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
        'remember' => true
    );
wp_login_form( $args );

} else { // If logged in:
    $args = array(
        'redirect' => home_url(), 
        'form_id' => 'loginform-custom',
        'label_username' => __( 'what is your name?' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'what is your password?' ),
        'label_remember' => __(''),
        'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
        'remember' => true
    );
wp_login_form( $args );
} ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Once the user is logged in the session is instantiated and you should be able to forward the user wherever you like.

```
<?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { // Display WordPress login form:
    $args = array(
        'redirect' => home_url(), 
        'form_id' => 'loginform-custom',
        'label_username' => __( 'what is your name?' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'what is your password?' ),
        'label_remember' => __(''),
        'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
        'remember' => true
    );
wp_login_form( $args );

} else { // If logged in:
    header('Location: /'); ## / redirects to root domain lvl
} ?>
```

Comment: thanks Joe, guess what was happening is that because I was logging in as an administrator, it was taking me to the dashboard. Logging in with different roles works.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense actually. If you want admin to redirect to a page other than /wp-admin maybe you would consider a plugin like theme my login. It comes with a whole bunch of other user login admin features as well http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/